# References in Java constructor

Tags: java, android

This is the first version of my code :

```java
public class ListSchedule implements ListInterface {

    private ArrayList<Schedule> list;

    private String cookie;

    public ListSchedule() {
        this.list = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Schedule> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

In another class, I made this call :

```java
protected final ListSchedule parse(String jsonString)
        throws CustomException {

    ListSchedule list = new ListSchedule();

    JSONArray schedulesArray;

    try {

        // Convert the response to a JSONObject
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        try {

            int errorCode = json.getInt("error");

            // Check if there is no error from FilBleu server
            if (errorCode > 0) {
                throw new CustomException(
                        CustomException.ERROR_FILBLEU,
                        "DataAccessObject", "Server error "
                                + json.getInt("subError"));
            }

            try {
                String cookie = json.getString("cookie");
                list = new ListSchedule(cookie);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new CustomException(CustomException.JSON_FORMAT,
                        "DataAccessObject", "No cookie value");
            }

            schedulesArray = json.getJSONArray("schedules");

            // NullPointerException with the line below
            Log.d("DAO", list.getList().toString());

            parseSchedulesArray(list, schedulesArray);

        } catch (JSONException e) { // Unable to get the error code
            throw new CustomException(CustomException.JSON_FORMAT,
                    "DataAccessObject", "Bad JSON format ("
                            + e.getMessage() + ")");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) { // Unable to convert response
        throw new CustomException(CustomException.JSON_FORMAT,
                "DataAccessObject", "Bad JSON format ("
                        + e.getMessage() + ")");
    }

    return list;
}
```

then I had a `NullPointerException` from the line `Log.d("DAO", list.getList().toString());`. So I tried another solution. As you can see, the only difference is the initialization of the `list` property :

```java
public class ListSchedule implements ListInterface {

    private ArrayList<Schedule> list = new ArrayList<Schedule>();

    private String cookie;

    public ListSchedule() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Schedule> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

and the `NullPointerException` was never thrown again...

I don't really understand the difference between the two ways of initializing the `list` property. Can somebody give me a hint please ?

Comment: if you can not understand the difference, you should read a basic programmation book

Comment: @blackbelt : I actually don't understand the behavior with the NullPointerException.

Comment: @blackbelt: Not really. His code is apparently correct. In fact I've seen this weird behavior before and couldn't find a good explanation. He obviously calls the constructor and the list should be initialized, but it's not.

Comment: I don't understand @blackbelt's comment.  In the first instance, it should be initialized in the constructor.  In the second, it should be initialized during object construction.  There shouldn't be any difference between them.

Comment: There's something fishy here. We probably don't have the whole code. Can you reproduce the bug by putting the initialization in the constructor again ? Are you sure nothing else changes ?

Comment: @dystroy I will give you the whole code right now ;)

Comment: You aren't showing us the non-default constructor, that clearly does not instantiate the list

Comment: @dystroy I tried to put the initialization in both constructor and declaration : the bug is not reproduced in this case.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Which non-default constructor? He's calling the default constructor.

Comment: @Tudor look at the code more fully, he later reassigns list to this call `new ListSchedule(cookie)` in the try block

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Good catch. That could be the issue.

Comment: `list = new ListSchedule(cookie);`

This constructor call passes an argument, but you aren't showing us any constructor in your code that accepts an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am speculating that the following constructor exists in your code base :

```
public ListSchedule(String cookie) {
        this.cookie = cookie;
    }
```

and what you need is the following:

```
     public ListSchedule(String cookie) {
                this.cookie = cookie;
                this.list = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
            }
```

This is further validated by the invocation of this line in your program:

```
list = new ListSchedule(cookie);
```

Notice how you don't initialize the list in the second constructor.  Also you start by invoking the default constructor, but you later reassign the pointer to the object into what gets created from the String constructor of ListSchedule.

Comment: I just made a mistake in copy/paste, now fixed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You code is calling this constructor:

```
list = new ListSchedule(cookie);
```

Which to me, does not call the one that initializes your `ArrayList<Schedule>` and that explains the `NullReferenceException`

Comment: actually that would instantiate a ListSchedule object that is what constructors do.

Comment: @Woot4Moo No what I meant is `ArrayList<Schedule>` not `ListSchedule`. Sorry for the confusion